# Keep getting Internal Server Error with resumable Jquery Fileuploader

Tags: jquery, html, upload

I am testing jQuery File Upload Demo on my server (link below) and keep getting internal server error, I'm trying this on a dedicated server and my maximum file upload is 30mb, I'm trying to upload a 11.5 GB  movie file.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I've have plenty of space left on server and I can't really put my head around it, I've checked the form validation as well as trying all types in their demo.

Looking forward to hear your thoughts

Comment: Max upload is 30mb, you're try 11gb, why are you surprised it doesn't work?

Comment: Max upload speed has nothing to do with this plugin, this is the purpose of it, it chunks the upload file into 1mb or 2mb (depending of how you set it). Im using this as resumable uplpad

Comment: Another note on that, it start uploading but gives error after a while